# How to optimize a model in a text classification task?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp

I am training a text classifier, using TextCNN, as a result, the `precision` is low(0.6), while the `recall` is high (0.9), as a fresher in deep-learning, I can not find the optimizing methods to raise the `recall`, I know I should observe the training data, check if the model is feeded with the related data.
but is there others reasons? is there some guide for model optimization？

Comment: What is your classes ratio?

Comment: @DenisGordeev label 1 vs label 0，is  1:10

Comment: I don't know what code you use for TextCNN; but in Tensorflow there are metrics for precision and recall. You can also use auc or f1. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/auc